# Android: passing text from an app to another one

Tags: android

In my Android project, I launch an application from another one, by using an intent, in this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("edu.dhbw.andar.sample","edu.dhbw.andar.sample.CustomActivity"));
        startActivity(intent);
```

And it works: the second application starts without problems.
Now, I wish to pass a text string from the first application to the second one. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an extra String in the intent (using [intent#putExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)) and read it in the new application:

In the first application:

```
intent.putExtra("IdentifierForYourString", theString);
```

In the second:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("IdentifierForYourString");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try immediately this solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the string in the intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("edu.dhbw.andar.sample","edu.dhbw.andar.sample.CustomActivity"));
        intent.putExtra("Key", myString);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your new activity you do:

`getParent().getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("Key");`

to get shipped string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bundles to send extra information from one activity to another, i.e.:

> ```
> Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
> intent.setComponent(new
> ```
>
> ComponentName("edu.dhbw.andar.sample","edu.dhbw.andar.sample.CustomActivity"));
>
> ```
> intent.putExtra("myparameter", "myvalue");
>
> startActivity(intent);
> ```

In the targeted activity you can retrieve the extra information like:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    Log.d("LOG", extras.getString("myparameter");
}
```

Hope this helps.